# How can I allow apps to claim "https" scheme URIs? (i.e How can I open a desktop application from https URL?)

Tags: linux, windows, redirect, oauth-2.0, oauth

Currently I'm trying to make a client for OAuth 2.0 authrorization flow, a Native App actually. And in the specification [right here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.2) it's stated that there are 3 ways to handle redirect URIs: Custom URI scheme, Loopback interface and **Claimed "https" Scheme URI**.

I'm having a hard time grasping how to implement this stuff, because I've tried finding it on the Internet and to no avail (I've had no such problems when I was looking for the info on loopback server or custom url scheme implementations, in fact I've managed to implement them).

I'm sure that I'm using the wrong words, so I'm asking for help. How can I allow apps to claim "https" scheme URIs? Some resources would be perfect. And the platforms are Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Claimed HTTPS schemes are only possible on mobile - via 'universal links' on iOS or 'app links' on Android. It would be nice if it worked for desktop also, but unfortunately that is not the case.

**MOBILE CLAIMED HTTPS SCHEME SAMPLES OF MINE**

- [Android Sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/29/basicandroidapp-execution/)
- [iOS Sample](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/how-to-run-the-ios-code-sample/)

**DESKTOP FUTURE DIRECTION?**

I guess your concern is a malware app triggering a login redirect with your desktop app's client id and redirect URI? This has been a concern for a while, though I guess if malware can run you may have bigger problems.

The future solution to this problem is likely to involve [Client Attestation Techniques](https://curity.io/resources/tutorials/howtos/haapi/authentication-api-android-sdk/) to prove the app's identity BEFORE it is allowed to attempt user authentication, rather than only relying on an owned response URL.

Right now the technology probably does not support what you want, and Custom URI schemes may be the best option.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about what means for "claimed".
When you "claim" a HTTPS scheme means that no other apps will have permissions to claim it? Is is safe to use it, for example, with OpenID connect redirect scheme?
Thanks

Comment: That's right - in mobile apps you can get the operating system to associate HTTPS URLs that you own with cryptographic keys used to sign your apps. Claiming an HTTPS scheme is done via an [assets file](https://mobile.authsamples.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json) hosted on that domain. The above links have more info and are hopefully visual and easy to read.